# Cumulative Integration Options With Julia

Tags: julia, numerical-integration

I have two 1-D arrays in which I would like to calculate the approximate cumulative integral of 1 array with respect to the scalar spacing specified by the 2nd array.  MATLAB has a function called cumtrapz that handles this scenario.  Is there something similar that I can try within Julia to accomplish the same thing?

The expected result is another 1-D array with the integral calculated for each element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a numerical integration package for Julia (see the [link](https://github.com/dextorious/NumericalIntegration.jl)) that defines `cumul_integrate(X, Y)` and uses the trapezoidal rule by default.

If this package didn't exist, though, you could easily write the function yourself and have a very efficient implementation out of the box because the loop does not come with a performance penalty.

**Edit**: Added an @assert to check matching vector dimensions and fixed a typo.

```
function cumtrapz(X::T, Y::T) where {T <: AbstractVector}
  # Check matching vector length
  @assert length(X) == length(Y)
  # Initialize Output
  out = similar(X)
  out[1] = 0
  # Iterate over arrays
  for i in 2:length(X)
    out[i] = out[i-1] + 0.5*(X[i] - X[i-1])*(Y[i] + Y[i-1])
  end
  # Return output
  out
end
```